# Android App: Can I show products different in a 7 inch tablet from a 10 inch tablet?

Tags: java, android

**EDIT: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE POSTING. I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO ACHIEVE DIFFERENT LAYOUT RESOLUTIONS FOR ANDROID, BUT HOW TO DYNAMICALLY LIST PRODUCTS IN DIFFERENT RESOLUTIONS SO THAT THEY FILL THE REQUIRED SPACE. CURRENTLY, 4 ROWS OF PRODUCTS SHOW ON THE 10INCH DISPLAY AND FOUR ROWS ON THE 7INCH. THIS MEANS THAT THE USER WILL NEED TO SCROLL VERTICALLY ON THE 7 INCH TO VIEW EVERYTHING. I WANT THE PRODUCTS TO DYNAMICALLY FILL IN THE SPACE WITH NO VERTICAL SCROLLING REQUIRED. THANKS FOR ANY HELP IN ADVANCE.**

I'm helping to write an Android app. In the 10 inch tablet I have 4 rows of products showing (this is what I wanted). In the 7 inch I should have only 3 rows of products showing, but are now showing 4 rows (like the 10 inch tablet) which is causing a vertical scroll. Is it possible to write code to show only 3 rows on the 7 inch tablet?

My products only moves right and left as intended- it should not have vertical scrolling.

To be more specific, the question is:  Is it possible to render products dynamically showing 4 rows of products in the 10 inch tablet while showing only 3 rows of products on the 7 inch.  The layout selected for the 7 inch is large.

Answer (score 2):

You Need individual layout for 7 inch as well as for 10 inches

**For 7 inch tablets**

- layout-sw600dp
- layout-sw600dp-port

**For 10 inch tablets**

- layout-sw720dp
- layout-sw720dp-port

**Updated Example**

```
res/layout this is the default, it is needed even if you don't plan to support phones!
```

**For 3.2 and above version Android Version ( >= 3.2 )**

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)

res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger) 

res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

**For less than 3.2 version Android Version ( < 3.2 )**

```
res/layout-large                       # for 7" tablet (works on emulator and nexus7)

res/layout-xlarge                      # for 10" tablet (works on emulator and galaxytab10.1)
```

Comment: Couldn't OP also use `layout-large` for 7" screens and `layout-xlarge` for 10" screens?